# python nonlocal - why sometimes need it and sometimes not

Tags: python, python-nonlocal

I know why we need to declare nonlocal in Python and am a bit confused about the following example. Without `nonlocal records` in line 276, `records` in line 277 is not defined. However, `records` in line 289 can be used without any error.
[image: without nonlocal]

And the following is the situation with nonlocal and it works well.
[image: with nonlocal]

Comment: Please don't post pictures of your code. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551

Comment: usually that's true but this is just a picture that makes the issue immediately obvious. clearly thought was put into using the picture. bruh

Comment: This should instead be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/370357/unboundlocalerror-on-local-variable-when-reassigned-after-first-use, but it's not worth reopening for that.

Answer (score 10):

A `nonlocal` declaration is analogous to a `global` declaration.  Both are needed only when a function *assigns* to a variable.  Normally, such a variable would be made local to the function.  The `nonlocal` and `global` declarations cause it to refer to the variable that exists outside of the function.

If a function does not assign to a variable, then the declarations are not needed, and it automatically looks for it in a higher scope.